# Code First and EF 5.0 not loading navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am trying to load a navigation property through Code First and EF 5.0 The child object is loading as null. below is the code.

```
  [Table("ls_roles")]
    public class Role
    {
        [Required]
        [Key]
        public int RoleID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public String BarColor { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
        public virtual ICollection<ScheduleEmployee> Employees { get; set; }
    }

    [Table("ls_ScheduleEmployee")]
    public class ScheduleEmployee
    {
        [Key]
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int RoleId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
        public  Role Role { get; set; }
    }
```

EDIT: CALLING CODE

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new Model.ContextEntityFramework().ScheduleEmployees.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

x.Role == null at this point

Comment: What exactly is loading as null?

Comment: Which is the "child" property that is null? `Role` or `Employees`

Comment: the role is coming back as empty when you look at scheduleemployee object

Comment: if the role is required, then you shouldn't have to make it virtual. not sure if that is stopping it. probably not

Comment: i removed the virtual, still coming back as null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to do a .include on your calling code to include children.

something like

```
Model.ContextEntityFramework().ScheduleEmployees.Include(x => x.Role).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. The code to make this work ended up being      var z = new Model.ContextEntityFramework().ScheduleEmployees.Include("Role").FirstOrDefault();

Comment: The include causes the navigation property to be eagerly loaded, which isn't necessarily bad, but definitely not ideal for a lot of situations.  The proper solution is to get lazy-loading working.

Comment: Lazy loading isnt an option in the current environment

Answer (score 8):

In order for lazy-loading to work, *all* properties on the class should be defined as virtual.  This is required for Entity Framework to create a proxy-object that supports lazy-loading.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to the official documentation that lists all requirements for EF to generate proxies.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Role` class does not need to use the `ForeignKey` attribute at all on the `Employees` collection. EF will automatically know to do the mapping based off of the `ScheduleEmployee` object and its use of the `ForeignKey` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
 [Table("ls_roles")]
public class Role
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public int RoleID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String BarColor { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<ScheduleEmployee> Employees { get; set; }
}

[Table("ls_ScheduleEmployee")]
public class ScheduleEmployee
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Role")]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }


    public virtual  Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some description of your code, in particular how and why it solves the problem!?